# Managing WSUS with Powershell. How to remove an automatic approval rule?

Tags: powershell, wsus

I'm writing Powershell scripts to manage WSUS. One script can create, read, and update automatic approval rules. But it can't delete rules.

WSUS allows admins to make rules with duplicate names. If there are multiple rules with the same name, the script needs to remove the duplicates before proceeding. I can't find a method to do that.

I'm pulling a lot of information from Microsoft's documentation on the WSUS Class Library (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms744624(v=vs.85))

The script I have needs to set an automatic update approval rule to the right settings.

```
$myServer = Get-WsusServer
$rule = $myServer.GetInstallApprovalRules() | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'WSUS Automation Rule'} #This returns data type Microsoft.UpdatesServices.Internal.BaseApi.AutomaticUpdateApprovalRule

#********************************* Need code here****************
if ($rule.count -gt 1){
    #If there is more than one rule named 'WSUS Automation Rule', delete the duplicates.
    }
#********************************* Need code here****************

if ($rule = $null){
    #If there is no rule with that name, make one.
    $rule = $myServer.CreateInstallApprovalRule('WSUS Automation Rule')
    }

#Snipped code. Create a list of update classifications in $classifications. 
#Snipped code. Create a list of update categories in $categories.

$rule.setSetUpdateClassifications($classifications)
$rule.setCategories($categories)
$rule.save()
$rule.apply()
```